# Android : how to play music and record from the mic at the same time?

Tags: android, record

I'm trying to make application can record my voice from mic built-in and music from android device at the same time. But my implementation make sound quality is too bad. Music sound from android device is too loud and i can't hear my voice. My code here :

```
            try 
            {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(commonHeader.getOutputFilePath());
            recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start(); // Recording is now started
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


            mplayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mplayer.setDataSource((String)downloadedData.get(1));

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            try {
                mplayer.prepare();
                mplayer.start();


            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                recFailed=true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                recFailed=true;
            }
            if(recFailed==true)
            {
                stopRec();
                showErrorMsg();
            }
```

Anyone can show me how to make sound quality better ?

Comment: Run them in different threads.

Comment: running on different thread doesn't solve the problem...
I've noticed that there is no problem with headset mic though

Comment: @elgui if you use the headset mic, then you can't hear the audio in the recording, correct?

Comment: @ThangBM have you tried reducing the volume of the music that's playing? It mostly about sound mixing than it is about coding. The right balance of the two will give you good result.