# Play audio file as microphone input into Android app

Tags: android, audio-recording, voice-recording

How can I play an audio file as a microphone input into an Android app? I want the Android app to think this audio is coming from the mic.

Comment: Have a look at this answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161587/android-how-to-play-music-and-record-from-the-mic-at-the-same-time
It might contain code that is useful to you, as the author over there wants to achieve for about the same.